# My (modded) Skyrim looks bad and messy

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

Today I started up Skyrim (after some months) but forgot, that there is a graphical disaster going on. Heres a picture of that mess:[image]

In the picture u can see that the grass in some distance is not nice to look at.
In addition to that my render distance has dramaticly sunk so that things like trees just pop up when im already close (but it isnt that close that im about to run into the new thing). I have no enb installed but a grass plugin (name: Verdat - A Skyrim grass plugin) which doesnt change the situation when disabled or enabled.

It would be great if you would have a solution form me. (I guess the problem is with the inis)

Comment: I'm going to assume you have checked all the video settings already?

Comment: Uninstall the mods then reinstall them one by one or if you no one's a problem then just uninstall that mod.  If that doesn't work just reinstall Skyrim.

Comment: Make sure you have a graphics card and enough RAM so that you can handle the increased resources required by the mods.

Comment: I have 8gb ddr3 ram and a gtx 1070 so it should be enough

Comment: ok ill try all your suggestions. thx guys for a fast answer

Comment: I don't think it's an issue, but 8GB of RAM could be a bottleneck if you're running a 1070.  I doubt you're maxing out your RAM, but for a system with a 1070 8 GB of RAM seems low.

Comment: @JMac with RAM when you don't have enough you notice immediately. When you have enough, having more does not help in the least. And Skyrim most likely doesn't use all of it - hell, before Special Edition it even in principle couldn't use more than 4GB.

Comment: @Deltharis  If you don't have enough RAM it doesn't always make itself obvious.  You can have programs in the background eating up resources as well.  Adding more doesn't speed you up if you never use it.  If you have other programs running in the background as you run out of memory they will have to transfer something to a page file instead of RAM and it will slow you down, but may not be clear why.  It's not super likely for Skyrim, I'm just more surprised they got a 1070 with only 8 GB, RAM is pretty darn cheap and they probably want to run some heavy games.

Answer (score 1):

As BlueBarren said in the comments, the only way to know for sure what mod causes the problem is to deactivate them all and reactivate them one by one. This gets much easier if you use mod manager like Nexus Mod Manager where you can simply deactivate mods without having to uninstall them every time.

After months, as you said, many mods will have received updates which could potentially cause compatibility problems with your Skyrim version or other mods. Always check for compatibility before you install a mod!

Answer (score 0):

RAM can be an issue, also in Oldrim with the ways you could allocate more RAM. I upgraded from 8Gb to 16Gb of RAM in SkyrimSE and it fixed all my problems with CTD, graphical glitches, etc. I now run 250 mods with no problem. I also have an older graphics card then what you are using.

Answer (score -2):

You should set your video settings higher.

Furthermore, render distance can be increased in game, under setting-display.